# Django 1.8: Re-render view on Database Update

Tags: django, caching, view, rendering

Currently I'm writing a view which displays data from my database. The data comes from an API call from another application. At the moment I'm updating the data every 15 minutes.

But now I want to update the data on every view access, unfortunately receiving and storing the data takes some time. So every refresh on the view takes some time for receiving, storing and rendering.
Now I like to display the current data from the database on the view at access with a message that the data will be updated. After the data has been updated in the database the new data should be displayed with a message data has been updated.

I have searched for different possibilities like Caching, Singal Usage or TemplateResponse Rendering but I'm not sure what will be the best method and how I can archive this in an elegant way.

Comment: You will need to use websocket to achieve the real-time update without polling.

Comment: You could always use ajax to refresh the elements on your page that would be affected by the database changes.